# Is there a word for the creation of something that solves a problem?

Tags: meaning

Is there a word for the creation of something that solves a problem? I've been using entrepreneurship, because at its core thats what entrepreneurs do, but is there a more specific word that targets the creation of something that solves a problem?

As a P.S., for the act of creating something besides creation?

Comment: invention for something completely new, innovation for an improvement on an idea or process

Comment: @pepper: or "innovention" for the combination of the two.

Answer (score 1):

An [innovation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innovation) is a new idea, device, or method and [device](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Device) is an object or piece of equipment that has been made for a special purpose.

Try using innovation.